# If a man is fully covered, not a single bit of skin showing, even the eyes, would it then be halal to record, since it’s not mimicking his creation?

Tags: halal-haram

Since only the clothes are showing and no other living thing, would it then be halal?

Comment: I am ashamed that I cannot find or remember a link or reference, but what I sure remember is that you must not draw or otherwise create anything that would be in need to have a soul, as for it is created by you, not by Allah, it will demand a soul from you.